# Live Search Using JSON, and Javascript but returns check for duplicates: insertTimeout in the console

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to implement a live search on a page such that suggestions are returned after a letter is typed on the keyboard and the user will be able to click the suggestion which will take them to the url. I have used the code below:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Live Search</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="searcharea">
    <label for="search">Live search</label>
    <p>Start a search</p>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="name" />
</div>
<div id="update"></div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript (main.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').keyup(function () {
        let searchField = $('#search').val();
        //let searchField = document.getElementById('search').val();
        let myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
            let output = '<ul class="searchresults">';
            $(data).find("name").each(function (key, value) {
                var val = value.firstChild.nodeValue;
                if (val.name.search(myExp) !== -1) {
                    output += '<li>' + val.name + '</li>';
                }
            });
            output += '</ul>';
            $('#update').html(output);
        });
    });
});
```

JSON: data.json

```
[
  {
    "name":"Value  ",
    "url": "https://strategyzer.com"
  },
  {
    "name":"Diffusion : The Adoption Curve)",
    "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QnfWhtujPA"
  },
  {
    "name":"Diffusion of Innovation Theory: The \"S\" Curve",
    "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiNoNYLBabA"
  },
  {
      "name":"Junior Officer Trade Back Office",
      "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/junior-officer-trade-back-office-1061443-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=2&sortBy=date"
    },
  {
      "name":"Machine Learning",
      "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/5-machine-learning-1061442-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=3&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
      "name":"Ruby Developers",
      "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/3-ruby-developers-1061441-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=4&sortBy=date"
  },
  {
      "name": "Sales Staff (Losgistic - Salary Attractive)",
      "url": "https://www.blockworks.com/sales-staff-losgistic-salary-attractive-1061440-jv/?source=searchResults&searchType=1&placement=5&sortBy=date"
  },
]
```

I have tried everything and its just counting and showing me "check for duplicates: insertTimeout" when I check it on the console.

I also used this code from another site with my own personalization:

```
<script>
    $('#search').keydown(function()
    {
        $.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
            var search = $('#search').val();
            var regex = new RegExp(search,'i');
            var output;
            $.each(data,function(key,val){
                if((val.url.search(regex) != -1) ||(val.name.search(regex) != -1 )){
                    output += "<tr>";
                    output += "<td id=" + key + ">" + val.cat_id + "</td>";
                    output += "<td id=" + key + ">" + val.title + "</td>";
                    output += "</tr>";
                }
            });

            //console.log(output)
            $('tbody').html(output);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This second code throws an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined
"
What am I doing wrongly. I have been on these for days.
I hope someone helps with tips and maybe a solution.
Thanks

Comment: it's not search, it must be `match` or even better is `regex.exec(val.url)`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: Also, in your first function you use `$.find()`, but find is used to find descendants of an element. So the way it's written, you're looking for "data" elements in your DOM, which don't exist.

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz

are you referring to the first JS code or the second one?
If yes, how´s the code expected to be written. Hoping to read from you

Comment: @AndroidNoobie, so how can that part be written?

Comment: i'm sorry @AdenijiOlasunkanmi totally oversaw it
`if(val.url.match(regex))` or `if(regex.exec(val.url))`